# Using CSP with nonce on React script tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, content-security-policy

I have a content security header containing a randomly generated nonce on each request.

All scripts within the html document have a nonce attribute with correct associated value.

All seems to be working ok except for a script loaded from within compiled React script

The problem:
The bundled React js file is blocked by CSP and not loaded by the browser even if I add a nonce to the script tag.

I use these CSP directives:
**Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-{0}' 'unsafe-eval' unsafe-inline**

This is how the script tag looks like.
@nonce is replaced at the runtime.

```js
<script nonce='@nonce' src='{someUrl}/app.js' defer> </script>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Samathingamajig the problem is that the bundled React js file is blocked by CSP on the browser and is not loaded even if I add a nonce to the script tag on the server-side code.